# Classifying Tricomi Equation with two ways

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, partial-derivative, linear-pde

Let's say that we have the Tricomi Equation from [Tsoumpelis PDE Part 1](http://galaxy.cti.gr/dep/sites/default/files/MDEI.pdf) (page 130)

\begin{align}
u_{yy}-yu_{xx}=0 \label{1}\tag1
\end{align}

We know $a=1, \ b=0,\ c=-y$
And we want to classify this PDE in two ways, so it would be hyperbolic.

1. The discriminant is:
   $$d=b^2-ac=y$$

So the equation has hyperbolic form when $y>0$.

2. We could write the above second-order PDE into a first-order system

$$u_x - \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}} u_y =0 \tag2$$
$$u_x+ \frac{1}{\sqrt{y}}u_y=0 \tag3$$

---

***Edited***

Let us differentiate the first equation w.r.t. $y$ and the second one w.r.t. $x$:
\begin{aligned}
a_1 u_{xy} + a_2 v_{yy} &= 0 \\
b_1 v_{xx} + b_2 u_{yx} &= 0
\end{aligned}
Using the equality of mixed derivatives for $u$ and the fact that $a_1 = b_2  \neq 0$, we obtain the equations
$$
u_{xy} = u_{yx} = -a_2/a_1 v_{yy} = -b_1/b_2 v_{xx}
$$
Since $a_2\neq 0$, we are left with the [second-order linear PDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_differential_equation#Linear_equations_of_second_order) $A v_{xx} + 2 B v_{xy} + Cv_{yy} = 0$ satisfied by $v$, with $A = 1$, $B = 0$ and $C = -\frac{a_1 b_1}{a_2 b_2}$.

So in our case
$A=1, B=0, C=-y$

Then the discriminant is:

$$D=B^2-AC=y$$
So the equation is in hyperbolic form when $y>0$

Is my consideration right?

Comment: @MatthewCassel is it correct or not? You wrote a comment ant you deleted it

Comment: I used the following steps from this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3082412/classifying-linear-first-order-pde-system-elliptic-hyperbolic-or-parabolic/3083251#3083251